# if statement to find item in list fails., python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a function to find out it a (x,y) is in a list and then do something. Even though I know the item (x,y) is in the list, it will not find it.

Here is the code I created:

```
possibles = [(x,y) for x in range(11) for y in range(11)]

print(possibles)

def if_possible(possibles):
  x = input('Enter row:')
  y = input('Enter col: ')
  item = (x,y)
  if item in possibles:
    print(item)
    possibles.remove(item)
    print(possibles)
  else:
    print('Something went wrong')

if_possible(possibles)
```

I have tried making item = x, y with out parenthesis but that does not work either. The else print('Something went wrong') anyway.

Here is the output: [image]

Are there somebody out there that can see what I did wrong here?

Comment: Your inputs are strings.

Comment: The `input()` function takes everything as a string present in `STDIN`.

Comment: Thank you! added and int before the input and now it works. Fairly new to Python so I apologize for posting such a stupid question when the answer is so obvious :/

Comment: It's works? I tried it , there is no reason for it , to not work!

Comment: @Tinadark no shame in asking, and your question is well written, so you're on the right path :)